# WP Video Autoplay blank in Firefox but with sound, in Chrome it works

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, firefox, video, autoplay

Hey guys I am a bit lost. I tried the best I could but I dont see why it's not working:

I used Wordpress to set up a website, the startpage has a video in the Elementor's sections background video function, which is saved under [this link](https://www.german-open-badminton.de/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/221027_Yonex_Trailer_MASTER_h264_20Mbit.mp4) 
I changed a few days ago the background video and since than it doesnt show pictures in Firefox, sound only.
This would be the website: https://www.german-open-badminton.de/
When I open the website in Chrome, it works
When I try to open in Cliquz, Opera, Firefox whatever, the video stays black I cannot see anything.
The video link doesnt work in Firefox.

But I dont see the missing puzzle :/

- I checked the source code part in Firefox and couldnt see any data lost
- it seems that I receive all the packages
- I checked my settings regarding to allow video and to not block it in Firefox- I checked also if javascript is enabled / true
- Firefox has the newest version
- Mp4 File video worked before as well in firefox
- the video is automute in the preseettings

Answer (score 0):

Alright I solved it - I used HandBrake to convert the video and shrink the size. It seems that during this process there was a mistake going on. I shrinked the video again and now it works fine :) –